# Recovering $\theta$ in Dirichlet-Multinomial (Polya) distribution

Tags: multinomial-distribution, dirichlet-distribution, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I'm working on [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) with Collapsed Gibbs Sampling.

LDA has two Dirichlet-Multinomial distribution and one of them is a document-topic distribution that determines the probability of using a topic $k$ in a document $d$. It assigns a latent topic $k$ to $i$th word in a document $d$, i.e., $w_{di}$ has $z_{di}$.

\begin{align}
\theta_d &\sim {\rm Dir}(\alpha) \quad{\rm (Document-Topic\ Distribution)}\\
z_{di} &\sim {\rm Multi}(\theta_d)
\end{align}

I want to get the probability of using a topic $k$ (in a document $d$), which is collapsed out in the sampling. I know the easiest way might be calculating

\begin{align}
\theta_{dk} = \frac{1}{N_d} \sum_{i=1}^{N_d} I(z_{di}=k),
\end{align}
where $N_d$ is the length of document.

However, for some reasons (which is hard to explain here and is not relevant to this question), I cannot use $z$.

Then, I thought the second best is to get $\mathbb{E}[\theta_{dk}]$. I checked  [Dirichlet-Multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution) and found the expectation for $n$ trials,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} (X_k) = n  \frac{\alpha_k}{\sum_k \alpha_k} 
\end{align}

Since I want to know the expectation of a single draw (which should be the same as the probability), can I claim
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} (\theta_{dk}) =  \frac{\alpha_k}{\sum_k \alpha_k} 
\end{align}

If I can claim it, what would be the best justification? If not, is there any alternative?

(Note: I update $\alpha$ in each iteration)

Comment: how is $\alpha$ updated each iteration?

Comment: @dontloo There are several papers on how to sample LDA's hyperparameters.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the sampling process. $\alpha$ is a fixed Dirichlet prior hyper-parameter that does not get updated.

Comment: @kedarps Here is a paper: https://tminka.github.io/papers/dirichlet/minka-dirichlet.pdf / I do sample $\alpha$ in my code and the simulation result is fine.